# Using LINQ to select desired results between two related IEnumerable query objects

Tags: c#, linq

I think this is kind of a basic question but I'm getting confused. I have two objects, `Orders` and `OrderTags`. In the database, `Orders` has no relation to `OrderTags`, but `OrderTags` has a FK relation to `Orders`.

So I capture both objects in my context like so:

```
orders = context.Orders;
tags   = context.OrderTags.Where(tag=> tag.ID = myID);
```

Now I want to reduce the orders list to only be equal to the orders that exist in my tags list. Here is my best pseudocode of what I want to do:

```
orders = orders.Where(every order id exists somewhere in the tags list of order ids)
```

For clarification, each `Tag` object has a `TagID` and an `OrderID`. So I only want the orders that correspond to the tags I have looked up. Can anyone assist me with the syntax so I can get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `LINQ` query:

```
var results = (from o in context.Orders 
                   join t in context.Tags on o.OrderId equals t.OrderId
               where t.ID == myID
               select o ).ToList();
```

Comment: you're missing a `select` here

Answer (score 2):

Using `LINQ` query:

```
orders = orders.Where(order => tags.Contains(tag => tag.ID == order.OrderID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a LINQ query with lambda expressions:

```
orders.RemoveAll(x => !tags.ConvertAll(y => y.tagId).Contains(x.tagID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
orders = orders.Where(o=>tags.Contains(t=>o.ID == t.OrderID));
```

You could also just perform a join.